# List.Fold_Left type system in Ocaml?

Tags: list, ocaml, fold, higher-order-functions

Write an Ocaml function `list_print : string list -> unit` that prints all the strings in a list from left to right:

So Lets say I've got an Ocaml function `list_print: string list -> unit` that prints all the strings in a list from left to write.  Now the correct solution is:

```
let list_print lst = List.fold_left (fun ( ) -> fun s -> print_string s) () lst;;
```

But When writing my solution, I wrote it as such:

```
let list_print lst = List.fold_left (fun s -> print_string s) () lst;;
```

But this gave me

**Error: This expression has type unit but an expression was expected of type 'a -> string**

Why is it that I need that first parameter fun() -> before the fun s?  I'm still new to Ocaml so this type system is quite confusing to me

Answer (score 8):

The purpose of `fold_left` (and `fold_right`) is to accumulate a value as you go along.  The extra parameter is this accumulated value.

You can use `List.iter` for your problem.  It *doesn't* accumulate a value.

You could think of `List.iter` as a version of `List.fold_left` that accumulates values of type `unit`.  And, in fact, you could implement it that way:

```
let iter f = List.fold_left (fun () a -> f a) ()
```

The point (as always with `unit`) is that there's only one value of the type, so it represents cases where the value isn't interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `List.fold_left`, that's fine, but you should start by reading the documentation for that function. The official documentation is quite short:

```
val fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
List.fold_left f a [b1; ...; bn] is f (... (f (f a b1) b2) ...) bn.
```

The first thing is the *type* of that function. The type is

```
 ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a
```

In other words, the function `fold_left` has three arguments and one result value. The first argument has type `('a -> 'b -> 'a)`. The second argument has type `'a`. The third argument has type `'b list`. The result value of the function has type `'a`.

Now, in your case, you want to *print* the strings. So you do not actually need any *result value*, you need a side effect. However, in OCaml all functions must have a result value. So you use the empty value, `()`, which has type `unit`. Therefore, the type parameter `'a` will be equal to `unit` in your case.

The type parameter `'b` is `string` because you are required to work on the list of strings.

Therefore, in your case the function `fold_left` must have the type

```
 (unit -> string -> unit) -> unit -> string list -> unit.
```

The first argument of `fold_left` must have the type `unit->string->unit`. In other words, it must be a function with two arguments, first argument is the empty value, i.e. `()`, the second argument a string. So the first argument to `fold_left` must be a function of this kind,

```
 fun x y -> ...
```

where `x` must be of type `unit` and `y` of type `string`. Since `x` is going to be always equal to `()`, it is not necessary to write this argument as a variable `x`, instead we can simply write `()` or even the dummy argument `_`. (The syntax `fun x -> fun y -> ...` gives the same function as `fun x y -> ...`.)

Now you can begin to figure out how fold_left works. Since this is obviously a homework question, I will leave this task to you.